# Flat GUI Design

Tags: software-development, gui, user-interface, gui-builder, visual-design

I would like to design the interface of a computer software similar to mobile apps, those which have a flat UI. What tools are available that give me the ability to design a flat and modern GUI? For example, a GUI similar to the following picture:

[image: Example UI with different sized tiles]

***Update:***

I want to design and develop a GUI for desktop applications which utilizes 3D scientific visualization libraries (such as streamlines, isosurfaces, vector plots, contours). I have found [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) which is a C++ library for this visualization purpose (maybe there are other tools as well). An [example](http://www.vtk.org/VTK/project/imagegallery.php) of VTK is shown below:

[image: 3D representative image]

After researching about VTK, I found out that it can be used along with [Qt](http://qt-project.org/). I also found out that [Blend for Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/) can create a flat UI but I am not sure if it can be used with VTK.

Now, my goal is to design a GUI for desktops (not mobile phone/devices) with 3D visualization capability that has a flat look (most probably using VTK and Qt). I would love to seek the community's opinion about this matter.

Comment: A suitable GUI designer is highly dependent on the programming language and environment being used. Do you have something specific with respect to this in mind (e.g. C++ with wxWidgets or Qt)?

Comment: You're probably going to find that it's not the GUI designer that gives you the look you want, but, rather the _skin_ (theme) you apply to the controls.

Comment: @ComFreek: please see the update in the question.